# Jsf custom selectItems

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

Look the following code

```xhtml
<h:selectManyCheckbox layout="pageDirection" styleClass="pressReviewTable">
 <f:selectItems value="#{theme.articles}" var="prArt" itemLabel="#{prArt.prLabel}" itemValue="#{prArt.id}" itemLabelEscaped="false"/>
</h:selectManyCheckbox>
```

I try to put some html on on the itemLabel like a `<b>` but i have the following error:

> The value of attribute "itemLabel"
>   associated with an element type
>   "f:selectItems" must not contain the
>   '<' character.

I find a trick to put directly in #{prArt.prLabel} the html but i'm not satisfied with that. I use mojarra and primefaces.

I want to do something like :

```xhtml
<f:selectItems value="#{theme.articles}" var="prArt" itemLabel="<b>#{prArt.value1}</b> : <font>#{prArt.value2}</font>" itemValue="#{prArt.id}" itemLabelEscaped="false"/>
```

What's the other way? If there...

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since each item label get printed as `<label>` in HTML, you can just use CSS

```xhtml
<h:selectManyCheckbox styleClass="foo">
```

with

```css
.foo label { font-weight: bold; }
```

Comment: I can't, in reality i have want to make something like `<f:selectItems value="#{theme.articles}" var="prArt" itemLabel="<b>#{prArt.value1}</b> : <font>#{prArt.value2}</font>" itemValue="#{prArt.id}" itemLabelEscaped="false"/>`

Comment: Well, then you can't do much in JSF/CSS side. A custom `f:selectItems` component would fix it, but that's a bit of work. You could just live with adding an extra getter which adds some HTML sausage around the values. Note that the `<font>` tag is deprecated since 1998. Rather use `<span>` or something.